# Entity Framework 6 for .net Core. In Blazor server side

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-6, startup, dbcontext, blazor-server-side

We have a large Class Library that uses EF6, which is now upgraded to EF6.3 so it can be used with .net Core 3. I want to use that library in a Blazor Server Side App. The problem is, I can't seem to register the connection string. In blazor I am supposed to put the connectionstrings in appsettings.json which I have done, but I can't register it because the normal way to do that (as far as I understand. I am not familiar very familar with blazor, mvc or .net core) is calling the following function inside the ConfigureServices method of the Startup.cs class:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>()
```

That method is an extension method form the efcore framework which I am not using. What to do if I use EF6.3(4) for core?

I have a WebForms project and there I web.config

Answer (score 2):

As I suspected, it was a dumb question. The problem was the Edmx file, which I linked from a .netframework project. I did that because I need the classes and the edmx file. I used this tutorial for that: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/issues/1748.

In order to get it to work I just needed to add an app.config file to the Blazor project and add the connectionstring which is used for the Edmx file.

The services.AddDbContext() was not needed at all.

Comment: But then how do you reference the context in your Blazor code? Can you explain that please? I'm facing the exact same scenario and I can't find info related

Comment: @gabriel290687
I just recreated the whole process to remember. I did a new blazor server side project in .net 7. Then I created a .net Framework 4.7.1 class library project.
I then made a project reference to the class library from the blazor project.
Then installed Entity Framework 6.4.4 in both projects using nuget.
Then add new item ADO.NET Entity Data Model in the .net framework project. Go through the process and add some tabels. Say yes to save the connection string and those unsafe options. You can change them to the more save options later.
...

Comment: Then move the App.config file generated in the class library project, to the blazor project. That should do it :)